# Error trying to open DB in SQLite (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

Am making an iOS apps with an embedded SQLite database. So I make my DB in a SQLite administrator and drag it to my Xcode project, like in the tutorial says.
When I try open my DataBase, I get this error: "out of memory". Dont know if it is a SQLite bug or something, but my file is really small to get a memory problem.

This is my code to init my DataBase:

```
- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path {
if (self = [super init]) {
    BOOL success;
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SoundLib_DB.sqlite"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath] == NO) {
        NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SoundLib_DB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
    }

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    sqlite3 *dbConnection;
//Here is when I get the error, at trying to open the DB
    if (sqlite3_open_v2("SoundLib", &dbConnection, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"[SQLITE] Unable to open database!");
        NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));
        return nil;
    }
    database = dbConnection;
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: You're not using the actual file path of your database in the `sqlite3_open_v2` call.

Comment: Yes, that `sqlite3_open_v2("SoundLib", &dbConnection,...` is not just fishy, it's wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error may be because you need to pass databasepath as `UTF8String`. I see you are passing "SoundLib". You can not directly pass like that.

```
 if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
{
   //dbPath is your full database path you getting above
}
```

P.S. Also have `dbpath` as `const char`

```
const char *dbpath
```

Comment: Anytime. Word of advice: Do keep habit of reading official Apple docs. Relying only on tutorials will build a weak foundation of your coding skills.

Answer (score 3):

Change your opening process so that it looks like this... It works for me ;) 
I guess your main mistake is that you forgot the UTF8String....

```
sqlite3 *database;
int result = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"Error opening databse");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I mark as correct the previous one, just because I read it first, but this works too man. Thank you.